# Button Borders appear broken in Android 4.1.2 using Ionic framework

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework

I created a small app using following [this tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=LLX2FEg0TjU).

App runs fine on Android but after running on 2 mobiles both running Android 4.1.2, I find that in one mobile the layout was broken. I mean button borders are broken.

Any suggestions on what is going wrong here ?

Using latest ionic framework and cordova.

Answer (score 1):

This mostly happens because different mobile screen size.
You should create different layout files for different screen sizes

For more information go here:

http://developer.android.com/training/multiscreen/screensizes.html

Comment: I am using Ionic Framework, is that true for that as well ? Actually in screen for bigger resolution, facing this issue with Micromax Canvas. I suppose in Ionic , it should take care of UI resolutions without tweaking much ?